# How to click first link in list of items after upgrading to Capybara 2.0?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

How to click first link in that case:

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="/agree/">Agree</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="/agree/">Agree</a>
</div>
```

```ruby
within ".item" do
  first(:link, "Agree").click
end
```

and I get this error:

```
Capybara::Ambiguous:
  Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css ".item"
```

And without the `within` I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: first(:link, "Agree").click
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can just use:

```
first('.item').click_link('Agree')
```

or

```
first('.item > a').click
```

(if your default selector is :css)

---

Code in your question doesn't work as:

```
within ".item" do
  first(:link, "Agree").click
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
find('.item').first(:link, "Agree").click
```

Capybara finds several `.item`'s so it raises an exception. I consider this behavior of Capybara 2 very good.

Comment: I would recommend against using #first, it doesn't wait for an element to exist: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afirst. If the content was created at runtime with JS first will return nil if it runs the expectation before the link is created.

Answer (score 139):

Try the following:

```
within ".item" do
  click_link("Agree", :match => :first)
end
```

Sources:

- http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_link-instance_method
- https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#strategy

Comment: amazing. And it works on simple page.find('#{css}', :match => :first).click Cheers for the really helpful answer

Answer (score 27):

This phrasing also works:

```rb
within first(".item") do
  click_link "Agree"
end
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Capybara 2.4.1 and poltergeist.

Answer (score 8):

most of those solutions will not use Capybara's brilliant waiting features

better do as this link suggests:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara#find-the-first-matching-element

## Bad:

`first(".active").click`
If there isn’t an .active element on the page yet, first will return nil and the click will fail.

## Good:

If you want to make sure there's exactly one
`find(".active").click`

If you just want the first element
`find(".active", match: :first).click`
Capybara will wait for the element to appear before trying to click.

Note that `match: :first` is more brittle, because it will silently click on a different element if you introduce new elements which match.

Comment: I believe this is the most accurate answer.

Comment: Confused. Looking at Capybara [`first`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders:first) it says it waits `default_max_wait_time` seconds and for [`find`](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders:find) it also waits the same amount of time.  I mention this as it's an old article that's been updated and I wonder if something might have changed?

Comment: Definitely this helper was the best option for me `find(".active", match: :first).click`.

Answer (score 5):

Xpath can address the element.  I'm not very good with it yet, but something like `//div[@class='active'][1]/a`

That may or may not work, but the point is that xpath can address an array of matches and pull out a particular one.  You should be able to match with this.

A working example example from one of my projects:

```
within page.find("div.panel", text: /Proposals/) do
  within page.find('tr', text: /Foo/) do
    page.should have_xpath('td[3]', text: @today)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since first() doesn't always wait, perhaps this is useful:

```
expect(page).to have_css("selector")                               
first("selector").click
```

Answer (score -4):

Simple you can use:

```
$('.item').find('a').first().click();
```

Comment: This example isn't relevant to capybara

Comment: Isn't that jQuery?