# Href link click using capybara

Tags: xpath, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

How can i click a link using capybara.I need to click the graduation link

```
<a href="/arts?Occasion=Graduation&amp;top_menu_item_title=+-+Graduation">Graduation</a>
```

I used following code
.but showing error message undefined method `click`

```
 page.find(:link,"Graduation").click
```

also used Xpath

```
page.find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/arts?Occasion=Graduation']").click
```

it is also not working

But my problem is my page contains multiple links of graduation.

so using  `page.all(:link,"Graduation")` r`eturns Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link "Graduation"`

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513377/how-to-click-first-link-in-list-of-items-after-upgrading-to-capybara-2-0/14517076#14517076

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
page.all(:link,"Graduation") returns Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link "Graduation"
```

That means page contains multiple graduation text link.so if you want to click the first one you can write like this

```
  page.all(:link,"Graduation")[0].click
```

It will click the first link and the below one click the second link.You can use anyone as your needs.

```
  page.all(:link,"Graduation")[1].click
```

am sure this will work for you

Answer (score 3):

First try using it without the `page` part. I've never needed it myself

Then you can try and find the link with the css for the exact link.

```
find("a[href='/arts?Occasion=Graduation&amp;top_menu_item_title=+-+Graduation']").click
```