# Capybara::Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath - Find 1st link

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I'm having an `index` action where I list all blog posts

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="blog-post">
  <h2 class="blog-post-title"><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h2>
  <p><%= post.sort_description %></p>
  <p class="blog-post-meta">
     <%= link_to 'Read more', post_path(post) %>
  </p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In my test script, in order to access the `show` action and view a single post I have this

```
find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/posts/1']").click
# or click_link(href: post_path(post))
```

But when I try to run the test I get this error

```
Failure/Error: find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/posts/1']").click

     Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "//a[@href='/posts/1']"
```

as capybara finds two different links which go to same page (one on title and the "read more" link). Is there a way to tell capybara to use the first link that finds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click first link in list of items after upgrading to Capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513377/how-to-click-first-link-in-list-of-items-after-upgrading-to-capybara-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of the links is in the title h2 you can use that to scope the find and remove the ambiguity

```
find(".blog-post-title > a[href=`#{post_path(post)}`]").click # always better to use post_path than hardcode the id
```

You could also do `first(:link, href: post_path(post)).click` but `first` (like `all`) has the disadvantage of not having waiting/retrying behavior so unless you're sure the page is fully loaded when called it's best to avoid it (or enable waiting/retrying on it by specifying one of the count options `first(:link, href: post_path(post), minimum: 1).click`).

If you need to click blog title links a lot you could also create a custom selector with something like

```
Capybara.add_selector(:title_link) do
  css do |post|
    ".blog-post-title > a[href=`#{post_path(post)}`]"
  end
end
```

which would then allow you to do

```
find(:title_link, post).click
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm accepting your answer as it was very detailed and also for giving this tip with the selector. I guess this script you put it somewhere in your `spec/support` dir or in `rails_helper` so it would be like a "global" setting?

Comment: @Lykos correct - anywhere that gets loaded before your Capybara driven tests start to run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use xpath.

In your example, you should be able to use:

```
first('.blog-post-title > a').click
```